# Z values get rescaled while plotting in 3d

Tags: visualization, matplotlib, ipython, 3d-reconstruction

> x_3d = 5.171875  , 5.3125    , 5.171875 ...  6
>
> y_3d  = 0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,  .... 1500 (1500 points)
>
> z_3d = -10.493983  ,  22.128998  , -14.582531  ,  34.687847  ,
>           11.390786  ,   9.852596  ,  -4.8797636 , -18.590075  ,
>           10.95118   , -19.660675  ....(1500 points)

Here

x_3d lies between 5 & 6 (1500 points)

y_3d lies between 0 & 1500(1500 points)[image]

z_3d lies between -100 & 100(1500 points)

But somehow on plotting the 3d scatterplot z values get diminished around 0

[image: 0,90 angle view]

I am using the code

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.view_init(0,90)
plt.scatter(x_3d,y_3d,z_3d,c=z_3d,cmap='viridis')
ax.set_zlim(-100, 100)
```

In the plot somehow z range is changing and settling around 0
I am very confused please help

Thank you in advance